# Boolean applies only to one quad

Tags: modifiers, object-mode

I try to boolean the cylinder (it is only one cylinder mirrored) to the car body[image]

This is the result I get when I apply the boolean, only one quad gets pierced

[image]

I tried to pierce the quads above and below, and won't pierce. I also tried the operation with a different cylender and it won't work either.

The object I try to pierce with the cylinder (the car body you see) has the solidify modifier active, but not applied

I also tried on the car body object:

Normals>Recalculate outside
Clean up>Delete loose
Clean up>Merge by distance

The Cylinder totally goes through the body I want to pierce
[image]
Do you have any ideas why this is happening?

Thank you

Comment: did you try both - fast and exact? if yes, please provide blend file

Comment: It worked with fast. Nice, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome!